# VBA object's Collection property contains data but won't let me access it (get EOF/BOF error)

Tags: oop, vba, excel

I have a class module in an Excel project that has a property called `Marks`, this is a VB Collection and has a public get property (but no set or let).

I can assign values to this without any problem:

```
myObject.Marks.Add 3.14159
```

However, when I try to do something with this object (e.g., iterating through it), I get an error:

```
3021: Either BOF or EOF is true or the current record has been deleted
```

However, if I try `myObject.Marks.Count`, it shows that the collection contains the amount of data that I was expecting... I just can't access it!

I don't really understand why. I am using the same process with other collection properties within the object -- even collections of collections -- and they're working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: That error does not look like one raised by a VB Collection.  It looks like a Recordset error.  Can you give us any code?

Comment: In the immediate window I get the error on the following: `debug.Print myObject.mySubObject(1).Marks(1)`, where mySubObject is another Collection. However `debug.Print myObject.mySubObject(1).Marks.Count` gives a valid result.

Comment: ...However, these objects are populated from a recordset: `myObject.mySubObject(i).Marks.Add rs!numeric_value`

Comment: @Foole Thanks for the tip-off. It turns out that the `myObject.mySubObject(i).Marks.Add rs!numeric_value` was the problem. Rather than adding the numeric value, it was adding a reference to this recordset field to the collection. I changed this to `myObject.mySubObject(i).Marks.Add CDbl(rs!numeric_value)` and it's now working... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myObject.myCollection.Add recordset!field` adds the recordset field object to the `myCollection` object, rather than its value. As such, simply casting the field to its appropriate type solves the problem.